# How can I get image files by URLConnection.getOutputStream() method?

Tags: java, asp.net

There is an ASP.NET web page to encode some images and save them to a specified folder...

I want to call this page by JAVA URL method,
but  I don't know how to use `getOutputStream()`  method to save this encoded images....

The following is my unfinished code :

```
try {

    String encodeImgUrl = "XXX.aspx";
    InputStream is = null;
    URL url = new URL(encodeImgUrl);
    is = url.openStream();

    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    // .... I don't know how to use connection.getOutputStream() to save this encoded images....


    is.close();

}catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```